# Is $rootScope the parent of the topmost $scope?

Tags: angularjs

I have a shared function which returns of the scope of the topmost element (document) in my AngularJS application.

```
function topScope() { 
  return angular.element(document).scope();
}
```

This always works and I am always guaranteed to have access to any subscopes located within the application (whether it be inside controllers or directives).

Here's an example of what I would use it for:

```
topScope().$emit('pageReady');
```

Now I've noticed that $rootScope also works the same way.

```
$rootScope.$emit('pageReady');
```

Which also works and achieves the same affect. But since $rootScope is designed to be the "$scope off the shelf" scope (any scope created will inherit it's methods and properties) then  does this still mean that it is in fact the topmost scope of the page? Thus being the parent of the scope object attached to the document node?

Comment: Yes, RootScope is the parent of all scopes.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`$rootScope` is a parent scope of all scopes *in a given AngularJS application*. Since it is possible to bootstrap multiple AngularJS applications on one page (only manually, this can't be done using `ng-app`) it is also possible to have multiple `$rootScope` instances in one HTML documents.

Each `$rootScope` is "attached" to either the element where ngApp was declared or the element passed into [angular.bootstrap](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/angular.bootstrap) as described [here](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$rootElement).

In short, the `$rootScope` is a root of all scopes for one AngularJS application but there is no "super-root" scope that would serve as a parent scope of all other scopes for a given HTML document.

In your case using the `$rootScope` might be OK if you've got only one AngularJS application in the whole HTML document.

Comment: This is correct. Side note, if you do have two $rootScopes because you have two apps and you need them to talk to each other, you can use $window... Seems like an edge case, but it's worth mentioning.