# Kendo UI button swith angular

Tags: angularjs, kendo-ui

I have the [following example](http://jsbin.com/UXohUjA/5/edit).

Two kendo UI buttons and two regular buttons. Both should enable/disable the button on bottom. Only the regular buttons do and I don't understand why. Probably has something to do with the scope...

**EDIT:**

From another example I have, it seems like the scope is updated correctly but the ui is not updated. In my example i have another control that when I click it the ui is suddenly being updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the answer:

When clicking the kendo button the scope does change but it doesn't go through angular so angular doesn't know that the scope was changed so the digest cycle doesn't run.
So adding `$scope.$apply();` at the end of the function triggers the digest.

Took the explanation from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16066170/angularjs-directives-change-scope-not-reflected-in-ui).