# angular js: Model not updating by $scope.$eval,$timeout and with $scope.$apply getting $digest already in progress error

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope','forecast','location',function($scope,forecast,location) {

// this will bring data on page load 
forecast.getData(function(data) {
//data bound to scope
    $scope.testData = data;
    });
//this will bring data on user click
  $scope.sendLocation = function(){ 
//Here is the actual call...  just put it on a button click.
   location.save(function(successResult){
     if(successResult.status === 200){
             $scope.$eval( function() {
            //data should bound to scope on user click
            $scope.testData = successResult.data;
            console.log($scope.testData);// successfully log new data to the console
            });
       };
      /* $scope.$apply(); getting $digest already in progress error */ 
       },function(err){
           console.log(err);
   });
}
}]);
```

Problem is that when i click, though console log the desired data but data is not updating on the DOM. As suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16066170/angularjs-directives-change-scope-not-reflected-in-ui) post i used $scope.$apply() at the bottom my handler but that getting error , I also tried $scope.$eval and $timeout, though that do not give any error but at the same time both are not updating model

Comment: what is the purpose of `$scope.$eval` in this code?

Comment: can you try this `function safeApply(scope, fn) {
    (scope.$$phase || scope.$root.$$phase) ? fn() : scope.$apply(fn);
}`

Comment: You will need to add example how you are using the data in the template. Probably ui is not updated because the reference is lost. Maybe you need a 'dot' in your model on the scope.

Comment: @ S.Klechkovski thanks for the suggestion, Yes there was some problem with the UI.