# AngularJS animate directive

Tags: angularjs

I want to add a class using $animate in my directive:

```
app.directive( 'animTest', [ '$animate', function( $animate ) {
  return function( scope, element, attrs ) {
    element.on( 'click', function() {
      if( element.hasClass( 'clicked' ) ) {
        console.log( '[remove]' );
        $animate.removeClass( element, 'clicked' );
      } else {
        console.log( '[add]' );
        $animate.addClass( element, 'clicked' );
      }
    });
  };
}]);
```

CSS:

```
.clicked {
  background: red;
}
.clicked-add, .clicked-remove, .clicked-add-active, .clicked-remove-active {
  -webkit-transition: all linear 0.5s;
  transition: all linear 0.5s;
}
```

But the class is never added.

Any idea?

UPDATE - added plnkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/zczgsnLuXONfU8U5mIuv - logs only '[add]' to each click

Comment: post your complete code or create a plunkr

Comment: your directice  work fine. what is display in console?

Comment: plnkr in post update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
      element.on( 'click', function() {
        if( element.hasClass( 'clicked' ) ) {
          scope.$apply(function(){
            console.log( '[remove]' );
            $animate.removeClass( element, 'clicked' );
          })

        } else {
          scope.$apply(function(){
            console.log( '[add]' );
            $animate.addClass( element, 'clicked' );
          });
        }
      });
```

you can check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16066306/6022945) for more details.