# 10 sec + delay in displaying elements using ng-repeat in Angular JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat, nouislider

Below is the code that I am using to display sliders on the client side (number of sliders obtained from backed).

It takes about **2 sec** to obtain slider objects from the backend and about **8 more seconds** to display the slider elements on the client side.

Could someone please advise me on how to optimise this to keep it with 1 second or lower. Below is my code.

Below is code in html

(Slider reference: [ya-no-ui-slider](https://github.com/Yankovsky/nouislider-angular))

```
<div ng-repeat="(sliderName, commonOptions) in sliders " style="display: flex; align-items: center;" class='col-xs-2'>
    <div class="vertical-slider " ya-no-ui-slider="commonOptions">
    </div>
</div>
```

Below is my angular js code

```
$scope.sliders = {} 

var commonOptionsSliders ={
   'slider1':{
     start: 0,
     step: 1,
     margin: 20,
     direction: 'rtl',
     orientation: 'vertical',
     range: {'min': 0, 'max': 100},
     tooltips: true
   },
   'slider2':{
     start: 0,
     step: 1,
     margin: 20,
     direction: 'rtl',
     orientation: 'vertical',
     range: {'min': 0, 'max': 100},
     tooltips: true
   }
 }


// Obtaining slider objects from firebase to display on client

var slidersRef = firebase.database().ref('slidersDetails');
$scope.obtainsliders = function(){

  slidersRef.once('value').then(function(dataSnapshot) { // Once the value is obtained from dB execute the below code
    var sliderObjects = dataSnapshot.val();

    if(Object.getOwnPropertyNames(sliderObjects).length !== 0 ){ // Checking if sliderObjects is empty

      for (key in sliderObjects){ // Iterating through sliderObjects
        var sliderObject = sliderObjects[key];
        for (key in sliderObject){
          var sliderDetailsObject = sliderObject[key];
          var sliderName = sliderDetailsObject['sliderName'];
          $scope.sliders[sliderName] = commonOptionsSliders[sliderName]; // Assingning options to the relavent sliders
        }
      }
    }
  });
}

$scope.obtainsliders();
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to reduce the delay time to about 1 sec by adding `$scope.$apply()` at the bottom of the event handler. Solution obtained from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16066170/angularjs-directives-change-scope-not-reflected-in-ui)

```
.....
$scope.sliders[sliderName] = commonOptionsSliders[sliderName]; // Assingning options to the relevant sliders
$scope.$apply()  // *** Here is the added code ***
```